# error: no such partition after installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 13.04

I have tried installing Ubuntu 16.04 from a portable stick. All went well I have selected 'Install alongisde windows 10' and after the instalation was completed I have removed the stick reboted the system and was expecting to see the menu on which I chose to boot from Windows10 or Ubuntu. But instead of that I got:

-error: no such partition
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>

I have tried some solutions on google but to no avail...Please help me correct this issue.

Mention: I wanted to install Ubuntu on my 120GB ssd along with windows 10. I was going to install Ubuntu on a different new partition so I have shrinked one of my partitions in Windows. But then during the instalation proccess I changed my mind and chose install along windows 10(I had 15gb free space on the partition that I chose to install Ubuntu on). I'm not sure if this mention will help much just read on google that ubuntu requires 25GB free space yet it did not complain when I asked it to install on a partition that had 15gb left.

Comment: did you install in EFI mode?

Comment: Hello. I'm not sure. I got that option during installation which warned me that i may encounter dificulties trying to run dual boot if i continue so i clicked 'force stop' or something and changed something there. Efi mode was mentioned i that warning altough i had no ideea what it meant :d.